# Creating HTML files using CloudStore / Blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

Is it possible to create html files using either CloudStore or Blobstore?

I want to create a function that will make post calls with html content to my GAE server, the Server will create an html file with this content and will send back the url of this new file. I think it's pretty simple but I don't find the way to do that using Google App Engine.

I would highly appreciate any help on this!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post (upload) all kinds of files, like html files and receive a serving url.
See this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133)